# amalgamated product of groups and representation theory

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

Let me ask a question which could be quite stupid, but still:

let $G$ be a group which is an amalgamated product of subgroups $A$ and $B$ over $C$:$\; \;$  $G = A \ast_{C} B$ (subgroups are infinite!).

Question:  How representation theory of $G$ is connected to representation theory of $A$ and $B$ (and $C$),  in another words, how $Rep(G)$ is connected to $Rep(A)$ and $Rep(B)$?

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: If you are interested in finite dimensional representations, then there is no connection because the amalgamated product may have no non-trivial faithful finite dimensional representations while $A$ and $B$ have faithful finite dimensional representations. 

Comment: I see, Thanks! I am interested in general about not only finite-dimensional representations, but such information is, of course, very interesting! (and probably, it holds then also in infinite dimensional case).

Comment: $Rep(G)$ is still formally related to $Rep(A)$, $Rep(B)$, and $Rep(C)$ even in the finite-dimensional case. In fact, we have $Rep(G)=Rep(A)\times_{Rep(C)}Rep(B)$ because a representation is just a functor out of $G$ and amalgamated product is the categorical pushout. 

Comment: @Marc Hoyois, thanks! I am just on the way to understand your answer.

Comment: @Marc: Maybe you should post your comment as an answer. This formula holds even if we think of $Rep$ as a scheme-theoretic functor (when the target is an algebraic group).  

Comment: To paraphrase Mark: If you are interested in infinite dimensional representations, then there is no connection either: view the free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ as the free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. A unitary representation of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a pair of unitaries on a Hilbert space, and that's about all you can say, while a unitary representation of $\mathbb{Z}$ is completely described by the spectral theorem (basically, it corresponds to a positive measure on the circle).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. As said by Marc Hoyois, the representations (finite or not) of the amalgamated product are just pairs of representations of A and B that coincide when restricted to C, by the very universal property of the amalgamated product. What else did you want ?

Comment: Now I convinced myself that I can forget about $C$, so I have just a free product of two groups (in fact, those groups are algebraic).  
But if representations of $G$ are just pairs of representations of $A$ and $B$, then representations of $Γ$ (in the answer below given by @HW) are just pairs of representations of $F_1$ and $F_2$ which seems to be impossible to me (following from the answer of @HW). How should one understand $Rep(A) \times_{Rep(C)} Rep(B)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote here is a stupid remark, I think, I got an answer!

Comment: Andriy: Google "fiber product", then Marc's answer will make sense. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me expand on Mark Sapir's comment with a concrete example.  Burger and Mozes famously [constructed a group](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=TI&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=burger&s5=mozes&s6=products&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=1446574) of the form

$\Gamma = F_1*_H F_2$

where $F_1,F_2$ are finitely generated free groups, $H$ is of finite index on either side and $\Gamma$ is simple!  Because finitely generated linear groups are residually finite (by a theorem of Mal'cev, say), it follows that $\Gamma$ has no non-trivial finite-dimensional representations.  On the other hand, of course, the free groups $F_i$ have impossibly rich representation theories.

There are some positive results that hold in special cases, such as when amalgamating over cyclic subgroups.  See, for instance, [this recent preprint of Jack Button](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2691) and the references therein.

Comment: There a much older (and easier) instance of a simple amalgam of 2 free groups (over an infinitely generated subgroup, hence infinitely presented). I don't have the reference available right now. It may be due to M. Hall or H. Neumann, I'm not sure.

Comment: This recent preprint: [Button - Groups possessing only indiscrete embeddings in $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2691).

Comment: There's also Bhattacharjee, Meenaxi, Constructing finitely presented infinite nearly simple groups. *Comm. Algebra* 22 (1994), which gives an amalgam of this form without finite quotients.  A more sophisticated (CAT(0)) example was given in Wise,  Complete square complexes. *Comment. Math. Helv.* 82 (2007).